# Modify returned array CakePHP 2.2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

I was wondering if there's any simple way to modify and add a new index to a given array at CakePHP.

Currently I'm doing a loop like this:

```
$posts = $this->paginate('Post');

$a=0;
foreach($posts as $post){
    $posts[$a]['Read'] = myfunction($post['Post']['id']);
    $a++;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific how do you want the array to be modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have to loop, but you could use less code:

```
$posts = $this->paginate('Post');
foreach($posts as $a=>$post){
    $posts[$a]['Read'] = myfunction($post['Post']['id']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nothing to do with cakephp, look for php cycles